# Using jq to beautify output in terminal using telnet

Tags: jq, telnet

Trying to use jq to beautify output in terminal in real-time using telnet

I downloaded and installed jq on my mac and I executed a telnet code in the terminal to try and make the output readable

```
telnet 192.168.31.2 8085 | grep -A 1 -e 'LOG DEBUG : sending a POST request to https://analytics-ingestion.staging-public.tubi.io/analytics-ingestion/v2/single-event' -e 'received' | jq '.'
```

I basically see a line by line outline of the output:

```
"event":{"page_load":{"category_list_page":{},"load_time":257,"status":"SUCCESS"}}
```

I was expecting the format to be in nice json format - I looked everywhere but I can't seem to find how to append jq on telnet

Comment: Could you post the output you’re seeing vs. the one you would want to see? Some example data would be helpful to understand your issue.

Comment: This is what I an seeing @bfontaine
"event":{"page_load":{"category_list_page":{},"load_time":257,"status":"SUCCESS"}},

Comment: @bfontaine sorry I don't know how to post json format but basically a line by line outline of the output

Comment: Thanks, I edited your question to add these details in it. I don’t get why it doesn’t work, I literally pipe multiline JSON in `jq` every day and it does pretty-print it. There’s no option to force the pretty-printing because it’s the default. Does a simple `echo '{"a": 1}' | jq .` shows pretty-printed JSON?

Comment: how does the output look like if you don't pipe the `jq` command?